# Generate key value pair using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have data like below

```
"data":
            [
              {
                "Id":"1",
                "Name":"first"
              },
              {
                "Id":"2",
                "Name":"second"
              },
              {
                "Id":"3",
                "Name":"third"
              }
]
```

i want to generate a list like

```
<select>
 <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

i used ng-options, but i am not able to get the desired output.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: `<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j4yoaub/)**:

```
<select name="mySelect" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in options">
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
</select>
```

If you need, you can also remove the default *Choose option* option, and set `selectedOption` to a value in `["1", "2", "3"]` so as to preselect a default option.

Comment: Do i need to use track by option.Id in this case?? or it is taken care?

Comment: No, do not use `track by` here. Read more about [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Consider closing the question if it is solved.